# How to get the form id in App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to get the id of my form, I create this form using the app script. because i was trying to make a onFormSubmit that will link my existing sheet to the generated form.. Thank you

```
 var form = FormApp.create(sheet.getRange(1,2).getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

First place to look - the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference).

See [Form.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getId()).

You could also use the auto-complete feature in the editor to view methods available on objects. Below the line you've provided, if you type `form.` you should see a list of methods that apply to `form`. You will see `getId()` in that list.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the information here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

The event has a Source (Document Source) and with the document source you can get the ID.

```
        function formSubmitted(e){ 
           Logger.log(e.source.getId())
        }
```

Weirdly this  "e.source" is not documented on the Form submit "Event" but i tried and worked just fine, here's the example.

```
1XE0UY8dddNsddas2Xszxiuz-g1h629ZYo8vDvn02Xn-1DaI
```

You can also grab other information if necessary heres a link to the "Document" Methods: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#methods

It's also good to point out, that the "**Document**" is related to the **Spread Sheet** and **not to the Form**.

The source "Document" looks like can be a polymorphic model because since mine example was pointing to spreadsheet I was wable to use the methods of the Class Sheet https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

So I was able to get the Sheet I wanted inside the SpreadSheet for instance.

```
Logger.log(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId())
 if( e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId() == "1.49122496E9"){
    Logger.log("Check by id worked");
  }
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "My Sheet Name"){
    Logger.log("Check by name worked");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `getId()` method:

```
var form = FormApp.create(sheet.getRange(1,2).getValue()).getId();
```